# Broken Mono C# code using System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-construction, mono

A couple of months back I started a relatively simple C# app which I was compiling with Mono.

I try to resume work on this today, and despite having an executable proving it compiled fine before, it is now complaining about System.Windows.Forms

> C:\Program Files\Mono-2.0.1\bin>mcs
>   ../projects/test_1/test.cs
>   ../projects/test_1/test.cs(2,14):
>   error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'Windows' does not exist in the
>   namespace `System'. Are you missing an
>   assembly reference?
>   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

I found a forum post of someone with the same error, and this was recommended:

> mcs Program.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll -r:System.Drawing.dll -v2

However, the -v2 argument doesn't work, and without it there are just a series of other namespace errors (ToolStripButton and similar).

I have downloaded the latest Mono 2.2 but this still produces the same error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
gmcs Program.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll -r:System.Drawing.dll
```

`gmcs` uses the .NET 2.0 profile.

Comment: curious, what's the g stand for?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Not sure why I didn't note that this was necessary last time.

Comment: generics.  Originally the compiler was a fork/branch of mcs to add generics.  Eventually, everything from C# 2.0 was put into it.  It was later merged back with mcs, but so many people are used to calling gmcs, that the name wasn't dropped.